# Under what conditions is a closed line integral 0?

Tags: integration, functions, line-integrals

In our lecture, the professor said that all closed line integrals are always 0 but in the notes I see that some of them are not 0. What are the conditions?

Comment: Exact differential?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? If the curve function gamma is exact differential, would the line integral be 0 always?

Comment: The integral of an exact differential around a closed curve is $0$, but I'm not sure if that's what you're talking about.  Google exact differential and see if it seems to be what the prof was discussing.

Comment: This looks like a good question to ask your professor (who knows the context).

Comment: Clearly the professor's remarks apply in a specific context. It is quite obviously false for line integrals in general. But in Complex analysis, a closed line integral in a simply connected domain of an analytic function is $0$ by Cauchy's theorem. More generally in Real analysis, a closed line integral of a harmonic function on a simply connected domain is $0$, and more generally yet, a closed line integral of an exact differential is $0$. The answer to your question depends on the context that you didn't include.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it! But the whole concept of why a closed line integral being 0 doesn't make sense to me. I can hardly imagine any integral being 0 except for a point integral